# grow a detailed object out of a low poly rigged object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

I have a low poly rigged human arm, and I'd like a second high poly mesh (an animated face) to morph out of the arm.  I have a few ideas, but before I get started I'd like to know how others would do it.

At the moment I'm thinking perhaps shrinkwrap and transfer the uv data from the arm to the border face, and then keyframe the materials to blend as the shrinkwrap turns off.

Any better ways?  They have different vert counts.

Comment: Does it have to be geometry? You might consider a displacement map, if the hi-res is only needed at render-time.

Comment: @RobinBetts yes it needs to be geometry because there are overhangs, and I don't think it's possible to generate a vector displacement from one animated mesh to another in Blender.